# Generate a dir for unix sockets WITHOUT systemd

Tags: systemd, sockets

In normal Ubuntu I used to create a dir for Unix sockets as follows (say for project `foo`):

1. Create a systemd script in: `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/foo.conf`
2. Place the following code in the script:

   ```
   /run/foo 0770 <username> <groupname>
   ```

Then on the next reboot the dir `/run/foo` will be created with the required permissions. The reason I do this is because only root can write to `/var/run` which links to -> `/run`, and its common for many apps to drop priviledges and change user before creating the socket, and hence they fail to write to `/var/run`.

Now I am using WSL2, with Ubuntu 20.04, and `systemd` does not exist. One can jump through many hoops to get it to work but they are buggy.

How does one create a folder with desired permissions which gets cleared after a reboot before any of the installed apps (e.g. nginx/postgresql) attempt to create their sockets (and hence fail due to stale sockets from before the reboot)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of init.d services you may be lucky by writing your full script path into a file
called `/etc/rc.local` (you may have to create it) and make it executable

Like so:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

## Examples: 
/usr/bin/foo              # a program
/usr/local/bin/bar.sh     # a shell script
/etc/init.d/foobar start  # a service

exit 0
```

*The `exit 0` is important!*

Then make it executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Everything in there will be started as **root** at system boot.

> rc.local is actually obsolete since **1983** and **may not work anymore**.
> When the then new, now obsolete SysV-Init system was introduced, it served as a workaround for retaining even older methods of system initialization and it's not recommended to use it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer gonna give it a try, sorry i think the bounty expired but the time I saw this =(. Actually surprised (and very grateful) to get an answer in the end.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get the /etc/rc.local to run (made it executable). It must not be supported by Ubuntu or more likely WSL ubuntu.